# Code with a ship which shooting wrong

Tags: javascript, canvas

I posted before but my question was not right. So Why my shoots are not following my ship which is shooting????? It is just stays only at one position even if i move ship away.......I added everything I guess.....Out of ideas..Any help will appreciated.

```
      function shoot(){
       context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.fillRect(X2, Y2--, 5,10);
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fillRect(X2, Y2, 5,10);
        if (Y2>=0) {
                timer=setTimeout(shoot(), 1);
            }
           else {
                context.fillstyle="black";
                context.fillRect(X2, Y2, 5,10);
                Y2=320;
                context.fillRect(X+23, Y2, 5,10);
            }

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a fiddle with my solution http://jsfiddle.net/YabH4/
I changed the shoot function to use player.x. and commented the below two lines

```
  //   context.fillRect(X2, Y2, 5,10);
            Y2=320;
  //   context.fillRect(X+23, Y2, 5,10);
```